# How to build a site and run on live server with Angular cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have Angular 2 SPA site. 
I want to run e2e tests in the Teamcity. 
I want to know how to build and run the the site on live server without a watch. `ng serve` builds, runs and watch the live site which causes issues in the Teamcity (console remains open)

I would like to run it in localhost as `ng serve` command does without watch option

Answer (score 1):

`ng build --prod` will build and bundle everything into the `dist`-folder.

You can host that content on any webserver.

Comment: I don't want to host it I want to run it on localhost like the way  `ng serve` does without watching

Comment: You can even "host" it on your localhost.. using any tool you like to :) all other answers are likely the same.. dont know why downvote..

Answer (score 0):

Within your terminal, `cd` into your Angular 2 project folder. Run `ng build --prod` to compile your sources. This command will generate a `dist` directory within your project's root directory, this is the only folder that you will need to have your Angular 2 project running in production. If you are using NGINX, you can set-up a domain to point to this directory and have the `index.html` file as it's index. You will also need to redirect all sub-URLs to the index.html as Angular 2 will handle the 404s. Similar concept if you are using Apache.

Answer (score 0):

With angular-cli:

```
ng build -p
```

will build your app for production.

```
ng build -p --aot
```

will build your app for production and use the Ahead Of Time compiler for a lighter app.

Comment: does it also run the site in localhost, like the way ng serve does? also I get  "0% compilingcompiler.AnimationParser is not a constructor" error running the script you mentioned.

Comment: You can easily run this built app on any server you own locally or remotly, just copy the built app, which is in the /dist folder of your app's project. You can use as example 'lite-server' to run the app in localhost : https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server